# Is there any way to change Python installation path on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

When I installed python, I've used the default installation directory, which is `c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37`, and now I need to move it to `c:\python37`.

Is this possible without uninstalling python? Because this will uninstall all the libraries and that's bad.

Comment: Yes you can change your path without uninstall python

Comment: Here was the instructions how to do this [Click here](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Comment: Can't you cust cut/paste the entire folder, and change path?

Answer (score 0):

Cut the folder and paste to the C directory and add the python in the bin to the path

Comment: I did this , when  I type python in cmd, it works, but when i try to execute any program, I crashes .